# need help converting php curl code to C language

Tags: php, c, curl

my service provider has given me following piece of PHP code for accessing his service. I need help in converting to C lang code for use in my application. The code is using curl module to post on to a site. 
pls advise.

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,  "http://api.mVaayoo.com/mvaayooapi/MessageCompose?user="myusername":"mypassword"&senderID=TEST SMS&receipientno="phonenum"&msgtxt=This is a test from mVaayoo API&state=4");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "user=$user&senderID=$senderID&receipientno=$receipientno&cid=$cid&msgtxt=$msgtxt");

$buffer = curl_exec($ch);

if(empty ($buffer))
{ echo " buffer is empty "; }
else
{ echo $buffer; }
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: <?php
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,  "http://api.mVaayoo.com/mvaayooapi/MessageCompose?user="myusername":"mypassword"&senderID=TEST SMS&receipientno="phonenum"&msgtxt=This is a test from mVaayoo API&state=4");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "user=$user&senderID=$senderID&receipientno=$receipientno&cid=$cid&msgtxt=$msgtxt");

$buffer = curl_exec($ch);

if(empty ($buffer))
{ echo " buffer is empty "; }
else
{ echo $buffer; }
curl_close($ch);
?>

Comment: I have tried libcurl but its not working. here is my effort the program gets stuck in the curl_easy_perform and never returns.

Comment: int main(void)
{
    CURLcode res;

    CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "");              curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 1L );
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1L );
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_callback);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        if (res != CURLE_OK) fprintf(stderr,"failed: %s", curl_easy_strerror(res));
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
    return -1;
}

Comment: for confidentiality reasons i removed the URL part.

Answer (score 1):

Use [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/) with it's C-interface. The remainer is good old C-style-string-handling.

Answer (score 1):

Your example libcurl program in the comment looks good, except that for a POST you need to install a CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, not a CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION. But if you just want to post a static buffer, use CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS instead of a callback function.